# npm install gives error -no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

Im new to this, so I'm not sure what to do. I'm working on a vue app, but when I try to run npm install on webstorm I get this error message. When I opened webstorm I got a message to run npm install, which I clicked, but then I tried to run npm run serve, but I got a similar error to this one. I tried to run npm install in the terminal again and I got this error for it too.

```
PS C:\Users\cwill\Documents\GitHub\ofo-webapp> npm install  
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\cwill\Documents\GitHub\ofo-webapp/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\cwill\Documents\GitHub\ofo-webapp\package.json'
```

This is what I have in package.json

```
{
  "name": "ofo-webapp-startercode",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Which directory does your `package.json` live in?